# Java Programming Challenge Code Not Working

Tags: java

I have been given a challenge to do witH Java and one of the questions I keep getting the wrong answer the question is:

What is the sum of all of the palindromic numbers that are the products of two 2-digit or 1-digit numbers?

Edit:
So I basically need code that will work out the sum of all palindromes who can be made from 2 numbers either 2-digit or 1-digit.

```
package projects;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Project3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Project3();
    }

    public Project3(){
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //generate 1-9
        for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
            numbers.add(i);
        }

        //generate 11-99
        for(int i = 10; i < 100; i+=10){
            numbers.add(i + (i / 10));
        }

        //generate 100-999
        for(int i = 100; i < 1000; i+=100){
            for(int j = 1; j < 10; j++){
                numbers.add(i + (j*10) + (i / 100));
            }
        }

        //generate 1000 - 9999
        for(int i = 1000; i < 10000; i+=1000){
            for(int j = 1; j < 10; j++){
                numbers.add(i + (j * 100) + (j * 10) + (i / 1000));
            }
        }

        boolean product = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
            product = false;
            for(int j = 99; j >= 1; j--){
                if(numbers.get(i).intValue() % j == 0){
                    product = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(product == false){
                numbers.remove(i);
            }
        }

        int total = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
            total += numbers.get(i);
            System.out.println(numbers.get(i) + "\t\t" + total);
        }

        System.out.println(total);
    }

    public String reverse(String thing){
        String reversed = "";
        char[] array = thing.toCharArray();
        for(int x = thing.length() - 1; x >= 0; x--){
            reversed += array[x];
        }
        return reversed;
    }


}
```

Edit:

I am trying to ask what/where my program is going wrong and what I could do to get a program that will give me th right answer.

Comment: What would you expect and what do you get? Did you debug your code?

Comment: Just create all the possible products of 1- and 2-digit numbers (not so many) and check whether they are palindromic?

Comment: Crucially, this isn't a *question*.  You haven't asked a question anywhere (nor demonstrated any attempts to understand the problem).  Dumping a bunch of code is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic goes wrong when you are checking for divisibility in the following loop:

```
 for(int j = 99; j >= 1; j--){
            if(numbers.get(i).intValue() % j == 0){
                product = true;
                break;
            }
```

Here you are just checking if the palindrome is divisible by a number between 1-99 but you are not worried about the other factor of the palindrome.

**Example:**
Let the palindrome be 2222.
When checking for its divisibility (inside 'j' loop), it is divisible by 22 and hence you are including it in the list, where as the other factor is 101 which is not a 2-digit/1-digit number.
You have to eliminate all such cases.

So instead of following this algorithm, it is better if you follow the algorithm in a reverse way as mentioned by few users above.

Comment: Thank you so much you have made it a lot clearer for me

Answer (score 1):

Just one potential problem:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
  ...
  if(product == false){
    numbers.remove(i);
  }
}
```

This might skip numbers. Consider the list `N,P,*` (where `N` is a non-product palidrome, `P` is a product palindrome and `*` is any palindrome). i is 0 and since N is a non-product palidrome it will be removed and your list now is `P,*`. Now i will be increased to 1 and thus the i-th element is `*`. `P` will be skipped - ouch.

To fix that, you might collect the palindromes into another set/list/collection and leave `numbers` unchanged.

Alternatively iterate backwards, i.e. `for( i = numbers.size(); i >= 0; i--)`.

A thirds option would be to use an iterator, e.g. `for( Iterator<Integer> itr = numbers.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) { ... }` and then `itr.next()` and `itr.remove()`.

Btw, you might want to use for a foreach loop whenever the value of `i` is not relevant, e.g. `for(Integer number : numbers )`

**Edit**: changed the example from `10,11,12` to `65,66,67` to reduce confusion. Please note that it's still an example and not necessarily based on your actual data.

**Edit 2**: I changed the example to something more abstract to avoid (or generate? ;) ) further confusion. Since I can't currently think of a sequence of a non-product palindrome followed by a product palindrome (`product` here means matching the requirement of being a product of 2 one- or two-digit numbers), I changed it to `N,P,*`.

I'll restate the point of my *potential bug* answer: when you iterate forward using indices and remove elements at the current or a lower index, you would skip elements, so don't do that unless you want that exact behavior.

Comment: I dont think the number 10 is present in the arraylist 'numbers'.

Comment: @Isp that was just an abstract example, you could use `65,66,67` as well. ;)

Comment: yea got what you meant in your post, but the array contains only palindromes where as 65,67 are not.

Comment: @Isp that's right, I'll make another edit

Answer (score 1):

You try to create all the palindromic numbers and then check whether they are a product of some numbers. Instead, try it the other way around. You already have a `reverse` function, so just do this:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    for (int k = i; k < 100; k++) {
        String s = String.valueOf(i * k);
        if (s.equals(reverse(s))) counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: He'd need the sum so it would be `total+=i*k` instead of `counter++` but that's a far more concise solution to the actual problem. +1

Comment: @Thomas I know, but hey, it's a challenge after all! :-P